# How should this c++ typedef using decltype and declval be written to make it portable?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, decltype, declval

I have the following

```
template <typename F, typename A0>
struct ResultOf {
        typedef typename decltype(boost::declval<F>()(boost::declval<A0>())) Type;
};
```

It was written so that VS2010 could have a **result_of** that worked for a specific use case. It is working under vs2015, vs2013 and vs2010 but under gcc I get a compile error

```
error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘decltype’
typedef typename decltype(boost::declval<F>()(boost::declval<A0>())) Type;
```

Is there an obvious small fix here?

Comment: How "portable" does it need to be?   old VS is a totally different beast, hardly fit to be called C++

Comment: Why do you use (std) decltype, but boost declval?

Comment: VS2010 to VS2017 and gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typename` keyword is not needed here. It is used, in particular, to denote a dependent type, like `T::value_type`, when a compiler cannot know whether `value_type` is a type. There are no dependent types in the present case.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `typename` works in clang, gcc, and modern msvc:

https://godbolt.org/z/CfOw-_